# XSLT: not contains check

Tags: xslt

I need to create XSL that checks a "does not contain" condition. For example, my XML is like this:

```
<Categories>
  <category>
    <blog>ABC</blog>
    <link>http://www.msdn.com</link>
  </category>
</Categories>
```

I want to show every `<blog>` where `<link>` does not contain `"msdn"`. I don't want to use equals because I just want to check part of the link.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what HTML output you want, but hopefully this can get you started.

```
<xsl:template match="category">
    <xsl:if test="not(contains(link, 'msdn'))">
        <a href="{link}">
            <xsl:value-of select="blog" />
        </a>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

You could also include the test in the template match (or the apply-templates select) predicate like this:

```
<xsl:template match="category[not(contains(link, 'msdn'))]">
```

Comment: I would probably check for `not(starts-with(substring-after(link, '://'), 'www.msdn.com'))`, to make the match unambiguous.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to check that not(contains()) count is zero

Comment: You could do add something like count(blog[not(contains(following-sibling::link, 'msdn'))]) to get the number of matching blog nodes and use an xsl:choose for the different sections.

Answer (score 0):

Use the not function with the contains function.

Example: not(contains('XML','XM'))

Result: false

> http://www.w3schools.com/Xpath/xpath_functions.asp

Comment: Thanks for the reply it solved my prblem but can you tell me I want to display msg like record not found when the count is 0 for not(contains(link,msdn)) ....how to achieve this

Comment: seeing as this is really an independent question, you should create a new post for it.

Answer (score 0):

Xpath for xsl:apply-templates or xsl:value-of should contain following

```
/Categories/category/blog[not( contains(following-sibling::link/text(), 'msdn'))]
```